# Tweepy api.search получает только 7 последних твитов, как получить более старые?

Tags: python, twitter-api

необходимо получить все твиты на определённую тему (например, содержащие ссылку на мой ресурс). Для этого пишется код из серии:

```
api = tw_oauth('./auth.k')
coursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='site.ru',  count = 20)
for tweet in coursor.items():
   ...
```

(пытался указывать количество интересующих твитов в items(20), на результат не влияет).
(пытался указать since_id равный последнему полученному твиту, или даже более старым, но тоже не влияет)

Однако на выходе получаю ровно 7 твитов. Вопросов 2:

1. Как получить больше 7 твитов за раз?
2. Как получить твиты старше (а не моложе) определённого времени или ИД? (Судя по доке since_id
   позволяет получить МОЛОДЫЕ твиты, ИД которых БОЛЬШЕ указанного)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По некоторым поисковым запросам twitter API может отдавать меньше результатов, чем поиск на сайте через браузер (почему не знаю). Именно поэтому я получил вчера всего 7 результатов.

Если запрос может дать через API больше запросов, чем указано в параметре count, то **ответ на вопрос 1:**

```
def limit_handled(cursor):
    while True:
        try:
            yield cursor.next()
        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            time.sleep(15 * 60)

for tweet in limit_handled(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='site.ru', count = 20).items()):
    print (tweet.id)
```

**Ответ на вопрос 2:**
Нет, нельзя. Документация Twitter API говорит, что для поиска доступны только записи за последние 7 дней. Хотя на практике удаётся получить данные за 10.

Comment: однако остаётся актуальным вопрос 2. Т.е. если в процессе парсинга твитера собрать N сообщений и упереться в дневной лимит, то не ясно как на следующий день продолжить с того же места. Параметр page = 2 в курсоре приводит к 400 ошибке ответа от АПИ.

Comment: эксперимент показал, что twitter API отдаёт данные примерно за 10 последних суток. Для этого использовался запрос вида 'site.ru until:2016-09-20'. Играя датой удаётся получить часть результатов до 19 и 20 сентября (сегодня 29). За 18 не получается получить НИЧЕГО. =(